# How should I persist a PanacheEntity with data coming from a Websocket message?

Tags: java, hibernate, websocket, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to persist the following entity when receiving a message from the client via *Websocket*:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;

@Entity
public class Penguin extends PanacheEntity{
    @Column(name="penguin_name")
    public String name;
}
```

The following persist works, when receiving a POST request:

```
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import com.penguins.demo.pojos.Penguin;

@Path("/api")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PenguinResource {
    
    @GET
    public List<Penguin> getPenguins(){
        return Penguin.listAll();
    }

    @POST
    @Transactional
    public Response addPenguin(Penguin penguin){
        penguin.persist();
        return Response.ok(penguin).status(201).build();
    }
}
```

However, the following code freezes when it reaches the persist line. The `message.getPenguin()` method is returning an actual `Penguin` reference (the `MessageDecoder.class` is doing it's part):

```
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import com.penguins.demo.pojos.Message;
import com.penguins.demo.pojos.Penguin;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/waddle/{user}", decoders = MessageDecoder.class, encoders = MessageEncoder.class)
public class PenguinHub {
   @OnMessage
   @Transactional
   public void onMessage(Session session, Message message) throws IOException {
        // Handle new messages
        message.setFrom(users.get(session.getId()));
        // it freezes on persist :(
        message.getPenguin().persist();
        broadcast(message);
   }
}
```

I'm  new to Panache/Hibernate, any help would be apreciated, thank you.

Comment: With panache, obviously. *rimshot*

Comment: The problem was that the `WebSocket` connection is handled by an `IOThread`. I was trying to execute a blocking operation (persist). The code was silently handling that exception so nothing got printed out in the console. Injecting a ```ManagedExecutor``` and delegating the persist operation to a working thread fixed the issue.

Comment: If you were able to cleanly resolve the problem, post it as an answer to your own question so that others who have the problem in the future can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked like this:

```
@Inject
ManagedExecutor managedExecutor;

@Inject
TransactionManager transactionManager;

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session, Message message) throws IOException {
    message.setFrom(users.get(session.getId()));
    managedExecutor.submit(() -> {
        try{
            transactionManager.begin();
            parseMessage(message); // persist the entity here
            transactionManager.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    });
}
```